# pasar Un argumento entre clases

Tags: java, android

me echan una mano con esto
como puedo pasar un argumento a una  clase desde otra que esta en otro lugar .
ahí puse maso menos como quiero que sea, pero no me acepta el compilador, seguro algo mal debo hacer
Desde ya muchas gracias ...
por ejemplo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

public class resive {
        private byte b[];
        public void data(final byte b[]){
            this.b = b;

            sendMessage(b);
        }

    }

}


}
```

y el otra clase que es servicio

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService   {


@Override
protected boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    
    byte bb=(byte)keyCode;
    byte b[]= {bb};

    MainActivity A = new  MainActivity();

   A.resive(bb);


}
```

...como le paso desde la class MyAccessibilityService, valores a la class, funcion data??

Comment: Que error obtienes, es importante agregar esta información a tu pregunta, saludos

Comment: no me acepta , la forma como lo estoy escribiendo, letras en rojo..

Comment: cuando pongo  A.resive(bb); , la A me la marca en rojo, no lo acepta

Answer (score 0):

Esto es incorrecto, a menos que tengas un método `resive()` estático

```
A.resive(bb);
```

Debes instanciar la clase `resive`  y llamar el método `data()` :

```
resive r = new resive();
r.data(bb);
```

Comment: hola, tampoco funciona, letras en rojo. me hace hacer referencia asi  MainActivity.resive r = new MainActivity.resive();
    r.data(bb);  , pero sale en rojo todo esto new MainActivity.resive(); y el argumento  (bb)